# how to convert a scientific notation number preserving precision

Tags: python, math, scientific-notation

I have a some numbers like:

```
1.8816764231589208e-06  <type 'float'>
```

how I can convert to

```
0.00000018816764231589208
```

Preserving all precision

Comment: Are you saying you have that value already stored in a variable, or you are have that as a string and you want it in a variable? And what do you mean by "precision": storing the exact value, or keeping and showing the "proper" number of significant digits, or other? Or do you mean you want to *print* to a certain number of decimal places? Your question as given is not clear.

Comment: You can format it like this: `'{:.20f}'.format(num)`, where the 20 is however many significant digits you want. I just picked 20 arbitrarily. Is this what you want?

Comment: first number is calculated as float, what I need a proper conversion from scientific notation to decimal, without any round

Comment: @peterWang I need a proper calculation, not only add leading zeros

Comment: The precision of a float is up to 16 decimal places so the scientific notation will be precise up to the 16th decimal place. When you are converting it to the other form you aren't changing the precision, you're just putting the leading zeros, which I thought was what you wanted

Comment: I hope you know that a float variable cannot store that value exactly. So if you want the value, as stored, printed exactly, probably you will get 0.000001881676423158920791458225373060653140555587015114724636077880859375. Is that what you want? If so, look at the decimal module.

Comment: Are these deemed internal or external representations ?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you would need to avoid the scientific notation for large/tiny numbers ?

Comment: To help deal with more precise floating point numbers consider using the [mpmath](http://mpmath.org) library.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy problem, because binary floating point numbers cannot always represent decimal fractions exactly, and the number you have chosen is one such.

Therefore, you need to know how many digits of precision you want. In your exact case, see what happens when I try to print it with various formats.

```
>>> x = 1.8816764231589208e-06
>>> for i in range(10, 30):
...     fmt = "{:.%df}" % i
...     print fmt, fmt.format(x)
... 
{:.10f} 0.0000018817
{:.11f} 0.00000188168
{:.12f} 0.000001881676
{:.13f} 0.0000018816764
{:.14f} 0.00000188167642
{:.15f} 0.000001881676423
{:.16f} 0.0000018816764232
{:.17f} 0.00000188167642316
{:.18f} 0.000001881676423159
{:.19f} 0.0000018816764231589
{:.20f} 0.00000188167642315892
{:.21f} 0.000001881676423158921
{:.22f} 0.0000018816764231589208
{:.23f} 0.00000188167642315892079
{:.24f} 0.000001881676423158920791
{:.25f} 0.0000018816764231589207915
{:.26f} 0.00000188167642315892079146
{:.27f} 0.000001881676423158920791458
{:.28f} 0.0000018816764231589207914582
{:.29f} 0.00000188167642315892079145823
>>>
```

As you will observe, Python is happy to provide many digits of precision, but in fact the later ones are spurious: a standard Python float is stored in 64 bits, but only 52 of those are used to represent the significant figures, meaning you can get at most 16 significant digits.

The real lesson here is that Python has no way to exactly store 1.8816764231589208e-06 as a floating point number. This is not so much a language limitation as a representational limitation of the floating-point implementation.

The formatting shown above may, however, allow you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The value you presented is not properly stored as Rory Daulton suggests in his comment. So your float `1.8816764231589208e-06  <type 'float'>` could be explained by this example:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = 1.8816764231589208e-06
>>> g = 0.0000018816764231589208        # g == a

>>> Decimal(a)                          # Creates a Decimal object with the passed float
Decimal('0.000001881676423158920791458225373060653140555587015114724636077880859375')

>>> Decimal('0.0000018816764231589208') # Exact value stored using str
Decimal('0.0000018816764231589208')     

>>> Decimal(a) == Decimal('0.0000018816764231589208')
False                                   # See the problem here? Your float did not
                                        # represent the number you "saw"

>>> Decimal(a).__float__()              
1.8816764231589208e-06

>>> Decimal(a).__float__() == a
True
```

If you want precise decimals, use Decimal or some other class to represent numbers rather than binary representations such as float. Your `0.0000018816764231589208` of type `float`, is actually the number shown by `Decimal()`.